# How do I merge 2 HashMaps together?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have 2 HashMaps of the type `HashMap<String, Integer>`. I would like to add them together in such a way that the values of duplicate keys get added together, rather than overwritten. This is the main reason why I can't use the `putAll` method for HashMaps. Is there a particular way I could do this easily?

Comment: Are you wanting to have multiple values mapped to the same key?

Comment: No I want the integer values of 2 equal keys to be added together in the new HashMap.

Comment: You want to merge two maps? When you looked through the documentation, i.e. the javadoc of [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), you didn't notice a method named [**`merge`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) that might seem relevant? You did **read the documentation** before asking here, right?

Comment: @Andreas To his defense. It is available since Java 1.8 and many questions like this are good content on SO for quick look ups without going through the docs (Let's be real we try Google Search first before heading the docs).

Comment: @MuratKaragöz Sure, *Google Search* first, then *javadoc*, and definitely *search here*, before creating a question. Seems **none** of those were tried.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Map#merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) e.g.

```
 Map<String, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<>();
 Map<String, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<>();

 map1.put("a", 1);
 map2.put("a", 2);

 Map<String, Integer> map3 = new HashMap<>(map1);
 map2.forEach((key, value) -> map3.merge(key, value, (v1,v2) -> v1+v2));
 System.out.println(map3); // a=3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use [`Stream.concat()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-) to concatenate the streams of the two maps. Then you can collect them summing the duplicates:

```
Map<String, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("a", 2);
map1.put("b", 3);
Map<String, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<>();
map2.put("b", 1);
map2.put("c", 3);

Map<String, Integer> merged = Stream.concat(map1.entrySet().stream(), map2.entrySet().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (a, b) -> a + b));
```

Instead of `(a, b) -> a + b` you also can use `Integer::sum`.

The result for this would be:

```
{a=2, b=4, c=3}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [map merge](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) from Java 8 :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       Map<String, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<>();
       map1.put("1", 1);
       map1.put("2", 2);

        Map<String, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<>();
        map2.put("2", 2);
        map2.put("3", 3);

        map1.forEach((key, value) -> map2.merge(key, value, Integer::sum));

        map2.forEach((s, integer) -> System.out.println(s + " " + integer));
    }
```

Output is :

```
1 1
2 4
3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to making simple one-liners, the [Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) is your friend. I would use the [`Stream#collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) method and the [`Collectors#toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) methods. For example:

```
Map<String, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<String, Integer>() {
    {
        put("first", 1);
        put("second", 4);
        put("third", 7);
    }
};
Map<String, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<String, Integer>() {
    {
        put("fourth", 5);
        put("fifth", 9);
        put("third", 3);
    }
};
Map<String, Integer> result = Stream.of(map1, map2).map(Map::entrySet).flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.<Entry<String, Integer>, String, Integer>toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue,
                (t, u) -> t + u));
```